# Is there a way to share assertions among test classes without inheritance in NUnit?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, nunit, mspec

In MSpec there is a neat feature that allows you share assertions between multiple tests. They're called ["behaviors"](http://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2010/01/18/behaviours-in-mspec/)

> Behaviours define reusable specs that encapsulate a particular set of,
>   you guessed it, behaviours; you’re then able to include these specs in
>   any context that exhibits a particular behaviour.

You define them as a class with assertions (`It` fields)

```
public class VehicleThatHasBeenStartedBehaviors
{
    protected static IVehicle vehicle;
    It should_have_a_running_engine = () => vehicle.IsEngineRunning.ShouldBeTrue();
    It should_be_idling = () => vehicle.RevCount.ShouldBeBetween(0, 1000);
}
```

and include them in your test class like

```
public class when_starting_a_car
{
    Behaves_like<VehicleThatHasBeenStartedBehaviors> a_started_vehicle;
}
```

How can I accomplish the same with NUnit?

Comment: Do you mean two tests running simultaneously? Or some kind of verification that is run for two tests? Do you have a code sample or link to one that uses this feature?

Comment: I want to have 1 class with assertions that is included in another class. Can't use inheritance. Example. http://lostechies.com/jamesgregory/2010/01/18/behaviours-in-mspec/

Answer (score 4):

You can use extension methods to "package" your type-specific assertions:

```
public static class VehicleAssertions {
    public static void ShouldBeStarted(this IVehicle vehicle) {
        // TODO: change these to NUnit assertions
        vehicle.IsEngineRunning.ShouldBeTrue();
        vehicle.RevCount.ShouldBeBetween(0, 1000);
    }
}
```

Use it on a test method:

```
testVehicle.ShouldBeStarted();
```

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a way to share assertions among test classes without
>   inheritance in NUnit?

Considering you just want to share assertions and you're testing for behaviors on interfaces, you could just create something simple:

```
public interface IBehavior
{
    void Check();
}

public class VehicleThatHasBeenStartedBehaviors : IBehavior
{
    protected IVehicle vehicle;

    public VehicleThatHasBeenStartedBehaviors(IVehicle vehicle)
    {
        this.vehicle = vehicle;
    }

    public void Check()
    {
        Assert.That(vehicle.IsEngineRunning, Is.True);
        Assert.That(vehicle.RevCount, Is.LessThanOrEqualTo(1000));
        Assert.That(vehicle.RevCount, Is.GreaterThanOrEqualTo(0));
    }
}

[TestFixture]
public class when_starting_a_car
{
    protected Car car;

    [SetUp]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        car = new Car();
    }

    [Test]
    public void behaves_like_a_started_vehicle()
    {
        new VehicleThatHasBeenStartedBehaviors(car).Check();
    }
}
```

BUT, if you want to specifically use MSpec syntax, I think you may have to implement it or find some framework that does it for you.

**EDIT**

Reading your comments on the question I realized you may be wanting to reuse test methods, and not simply assertions. If that's the case, you could write a [customized addin for NUnit](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=nunitAddins&r=2.6.1).  That may sound a little overkill, but it's up to you to decide.

My **starting point** would be writing a customized [SuiteBuilder](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=suiteBuilders&r=2.6.1) object:

> **Purpose**
>
> A SuiteBuilder is an addin used to build a test fixture from a type.
>   NUnit itself uses a SuiteBuilder to recognize and build TestFixtures.

Using your own suite builder you could read some behavior classes and compose your fixture.

```
[NUnitAddin]
public class TestCompositionAddinProvider : IAddin
{
    #region IAddin Members

    public bool Install(IExtensionHost host)
    {
        IExtensionPoint builders = host.GetExtensionPoint("SuiteBuilders");
        if (builders == null)
            return false;
        builders.Install(new TestCompositionSuiteBuilder());
        return true;
    }

    #endregion
}
public class TestCompositionSuiteBuilder : ISuiteBuilder
{
    #region ISuiteBuilder Members

    public bool CanBuildFrom(Type type)
    {
                    //TODO: Create validation logic
        return true;
    }

    public NUnit.Core.Test BuildFrom(Type type)
    {
        if (CanBuildFrom(type))
            return new ComposedSuiteExtension(type);
        return null;
    }

    #endregion
}

public class ComposedSuiteExtension : TestSuite
{
    public ComposedSuiteExtension(Type fixtureType)
        : base(fixtureType)
    {
        //TODO: Create logic to add test methods from various behaviors.
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like we don't have this solution in NUnit 3 but I'm not sure what replaced it.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at the [Mixin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin) concept.

Here is an SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6644668/mixins-with-c-sharp-4-0) describing how to accomplish this with C# 4.0

Comment: But, I don't think that this approach will work for the NUnit test runner out of the box. It uses basic reflection to find classes/methods decorated with their specific attributes. This is a dynamic-ish lookup?

Answer (score 1):

Another simple solution is to create static Assertion methods in a Helper class that you call in each applicable test. For instance like so:

```
public static class VehicleAssert 
{
    public void AssertCorrectlyStarted(IVehicle car) 
    {
         vehicle.IsEngineRunning.ShouldBeTrue();
         vehicle.RevCount.ShouldBeBetween(0, 1000); 
    }
 }
```

Then in each testfixture use it like this:

```
[TestFixture]
public class CarTest 
{
     [Test]
     public void TestCarStartsCorrectly() 
     {
         var car = new Car();
         car.Start();
         VehicleAssert.AssertCorrectlyStarted(car);
     }
}
```